# Is it possible to migrate project data from a SonarQube instance to another?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

In our intranet we have two SonarQube instances.

They contain two distinct sets of projects data.

Is there a way to merge the two sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's not. The best you can do is recreate the data from one server in the other using the `sonar.projectDate` analysis property. [More here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).

**Edit**
This is now available in the [Governance](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/)($) plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I was able to propose a feature for SonarQube, this would be one! :-)